# Formato inválido - Bootstrap Datetimepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, datepicker

Buenas!

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que uso un par de Datetimepickers para delimitar fechas en una consulta. Uso Firefox y todo estaba bien, es cuando pruebo en Chrome y me aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me agarra el formato que tenía fijado por el código de Javascript (soy bastante nuevo en este lenguaje y mi conocimiento lo estoy agarrando con la práctica). Esto de por sí era un problema, ya que en la base de datos el formato de la fecha es el universal (aaaa-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ms). Mi idea para solventar esto después de acomodar un poco la base de datos que ya estaba hecha, era formatear el dato en php para luego hacer la consulta.

Sin embargo ahora me aparece este problema. En la consola aparece el siguiente error/advertencia:

> The specified value "09/08/2017 10:46 AM" does not conform to the
>   required format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

[image: Error extenso]

¿Qué podría hacer para solventar esto? Ya que estamos, me gustaría transformar de una vez el formato para que sea el mismo que el del campo en SQL y así ahorrarme la conversión luego, las personas a las que les estoy haciendo el proyecto me dicen que no tienen problema en el formato de la fecha y la hora.

Anexo cómo se ve en Firefox y el código Javascript que tiene el Datetimepicker.

```
$(function () {
        $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker();
        $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
            useCurrent: false //Important! See issue #1075
        });
        $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker7').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
        });
        $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function (e) {
            $('#datetimepicker6').data("DateTimePicker").maxDate(e.date);
        });
    });
```

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui una solucion! Simplemente agregar el atributo data-date-format=" " a la etiqueta input. Dentro de las comillas coloque el formato que buscaba y me quedo asi:

```
`<input type='date' class="form-control" name="to" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD"/>`
```

Muchas gracias a los que me ayudaron!